# Calculating Cosine Similarity of two Vectors of Different Size

Tags: math, vector, nlp, dot-product, cosine-similarity

I have 2 questions,

1. I've made a vector from a document by finding out how many times each word appeared in a document. Is this the right way of making the vector? Or do I have to do something else also?
2. Using the above method I've created vectors of 16 documents, which are of different sizes. Now i want to apply cosine similarity to find out how similar each document is. The problem I'm having is getting the dot product of two vectors because they are of different sizes. How would i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Sounds reasonable, as long as it means you have a list/map/dict/hash of `(word, count)` pairs as your vector representation.
2. You should [pretend that you have zero values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) for the words that do not occur in some vector, without storing these zeros anywhere. Then, you can use the following algorithm to compute the dot product of these vectors (pseudocode):

   ```
   algorithm dot_product(a : WordVector, b : WordVector):
       dot = 0
       for word, x in a do
           y = lookup(word, b)
           dot += x * y
       return dot
   ```

   The `lookup` part can be anything, but for speed, I'd use hashtables as the vector representation (e.g. Python's `dict`).

Comment: At the moment i have just the word counts in an `ArrayList` but i can easily change it to <word, count> HashMap ... from your answer to question 2, how would i put 0's in vector A for the words that occur in vector B?

Comment: @Raiden: you don't actually put the zeros in anywhere. You just pretend that they are there and in effect use a [sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) vector.

Comment: Hmmm I see what you mean, but how would i know that I hypothetically placed the zero at the right spot? You get what im saying?

Comment: @Raiden: no, I don't. You know which words you've seen, right? And you've stored all of them. So all the other words have zero value, but that doesn't matter as zeros don't affect the value of the dot product.